# Rotating fluid under gravity, fluid dynamics question

Tags: fluid-dynamics

An incompressible inviscid ﬂuid is rotating under gravity g with constant angular
velocity $\Omega$ about the z-axis, which is vertical, so that $u = (−\Omega y, \Omega x, 0)$ relative
to ﬁxed Cartesian axes. We wish to ﬁnd the surfaces of constant pressure, and
hence surface of a uniformly rotating bucket of water (which will be at atmospheric
pressure).
Bernoulli's equation suggests that $$p/\rho+|u|^2/2+gz=\text{constant. So,}$$

$$z=\text{constant}-\frac{\Omega^2}{2g}(x^2+y^2)$$

But this suggests that the surface of a rotating bucket of water is at its highest in
the middle, where is this going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Physics Forums you should find the answer to your exact problem ['Fluid dynamics - finding pressure for a rotating fluid'](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=476134). Another answer is [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=38112) (the point is that Bernoulli's law is applicable only along a streamline so that we must use a rotating frame and add the centripetal acceleration).

From another point of view see Newton's ['Bucket argument'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_argument).